# Azure Webjob for monitoring service(API)

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs, azure-webjobssdk, azure-webjobs-continuous

I needed some feedback on how to configure Azure Webjob for below requirement.

- Need to have only one Web job. In that Webjob, need to have one function for each service(API) for multiple Geo's(Ex: WestUS and Central US).
- WebJob should run for every 5 mins.
- It should call only GET endpoints of services and should validate HTTP status codes and response body.
- Each run of each end-point should make an entry in Table(Configuration => Method Name, URL, IsActive)

Ex:
MethodName       URL        IsActive

---

GetUsers         XXXX       1

GetProducts      XXXX       0

- Each failure i.e other than HttpStatus code 2XX should trigger an email to configured audience + Team channel alerts by picking up DB configuration;this DB should be available in multiple Geo's.

Any help in implementation would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have WAY too many questions in here. In it's current form, this question is no fit for SO. Please refer to [ask].

Comment: Can someone please re-open this and give suggestions??

Answer (score 1):

Azure Application Insights provides built-in tests for this.

> There are three types of availability tests:
>
> - URL ping test: a simple test that you can create in the Azure portal.
> - Multi-step web test: A recording of a sequence of web requests, which can be played back to test more complex scenarios. Multi-step web tests are created in Visual Studio Enterprise and uploaded to the portal for execution.
> - Custom Track Availability Tests: If you decide to create a custom application to run availability tests, the TrackAvailability() method can be used to send the results to Application Insights.
>   You can create up to 100 availability tests per Application Insights resource.

Source: [Monitor the availability of any website](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/monitor-web-app-availability)